# C# null propagation operator inside if condition statement

Tags: c#, null-propagation-operator

Let's say I want to write something like:

```
    static string Foo(dynamic d, string key)
    {
        var dict =  d as IDictionary<string, string>;

        if (dict?.TryGetValue(key, out string result) ?? false)
        {
            return result;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

It gives compile error: `Local variable 'result' migth not be initialized before accessing`

I wonder why c# compiler doesn't sure about the control flow in this case.

We all know that most of time c# compiler behaves "smart" when it sees constant values.

Comment: Your question might be already answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684826/null-propagation-operator-out-parameters-and-false-compiler-errors)

Comment: Yes. Its duplicate. I couldn't find it before ask. Thank you.