# Optional null coalescence in if clause

Tags: c#

A colleague of mine just encountered an interesting problem. I recreated the issue with a simple example code below. The problem is that the compiler complains about `i` possibly not being assigned when it is used in the third line.

I know that `GetProperty` will not be executed, if `o` is `null`, and `i` will then not be initialized, but in that case I would also not evalueate `int i2 = i;`. Is there something about optionals or the null coalescing opertator I don't know that is relevant here, or is this simply a case where the compiler isn't intelligent enough to know that `i` is not used if it is not initialized?

```
void Test(object o) {
    if (o?.GetProperty("Blah", out int i) ?? false) {
        int i2 = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the compiler just isn't that "smart". It can't make the conclusion that the "null propagation program path" `object o = null; if(o?.GetProperty("Blah", out int i) ..`  will be caught by the `?? false` part of the if statement

Comment: @Piflik You could split out variable from argument and initialise there.

Answer (score 6):

you are using **Null Conditional Access** with `o?` which means that there is a possibility that (whenever o is null) `GetProperty` will not be called.

This introduces posibility of uninitialized `i`. because `out int i` won't be called in the case that `o` is null.

the code can be tested by removing null conditional access

```
void Test(SomeClass o) {
    if (o.GetProperty("Blah", out int i) ?? false) {
        int i2 = i; //no-compiler error 
    }
}
```

on the above method, GetProperty method is always called and thus `i` is always initialized and assigned.

---

On the other hand your code does not compile, `object o` does not have `.GetProperty` method on its own

---

```
if (o?.GetProperty("Blah", out int i) ?? false)
```

can be expanded as

```
if (o != null)
{
     if (o.GetProperty("Blah", out int i))
     {
     }
}
else
{
     //i is not defined in this context //
}
```

Comment: Would the downvoter indicate why Simonare's answer is wrong?

Comment: @John I see no value in this answer. It just states a fact which OP is already aware of (as described in the question).

Comment: so what do you expect? I am describing how the compiler behaves. Do you have any other suggestion on this? The error is expected and logical as it is described above

Comment: @Simonare Maybe adding why the compiler is not aware of the fact that the "true" path of the if statement will not be executed if `o` is NULL and therefore `i` uninitialized. Or something between those lines. I don't have a great answer either.

Comment: I know that I can't use uninitialized variables and also that `GetProperty` will not be executed if `o` is null, but the only line that uses the then uninitialized variable will also not be executed in that case. `GetProperty` is an extension method I wrote. It uses reflection to get the value of a property, but that is not important for the question, I just needed a function with an `out` parameter.

Comment: @croxy can you please check my edited answer?

Comment: @Simonare Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47685008/5453249 this answers OPs question perfectly in my opinion.

Comment: @Simonare in your expanded code example, the else block does not *use* `i`, and therefore there should be no compiler error.